# Apache Flink: Can I get the name of the key field in a WindowFunction?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a DataStream have different fields that I want to keyBy to do aggregated computation on (count, average, ..)

```
stream.keyBy("field1").window().aggregate(AggFunc, WindowFunc)...

stream.keyBy("field2").window().aggregate(AggFunc, WindowFunc)...

stream.keyBy("field3").window().aggregate(AggFunc, WindowFunc)...
```

**Is there a way to get name of the keyed field in later WindowFunc ("field1", "field2", "field3")?**
Note that I want the field name "field1" not the field possible values (this I already have in key in apply function of WindowFunction).

The reason: I want to **use the same WindowFunc for 3 aggregations** - here I add window_start_time, **key_field_name**, key_value to the result.

Wanted result example:

-stream keyed on field1

```
("field1", "field1-val1", 3, window1)
("field1", "field1-val2", 5, window1)
```

-stream keyed on field2

```
("field2", "field2-val1", 6, window1)
("field2", "field2-val2", 7, window1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the `WindowFunction` does not give access to the name of a key field.
However, you can add a parameter to the constructor of your `WindowFunction` and pass the field name there.

This would look similar to the following example

```
// define window function

public static class MyWindowFunc implements WindowFunction<...> { 
    private final String keyname;

    public MyWindowFunc(String keyname) {
        this.keyname = keyname;
    }    

  ...
}

// use window function

stream.keyBy("field1").window().aggregate(AggFunc, new MyWindowFunc("field1"))...
stream.keyBy("field2").window().aggregate(AggFunc, new MyWindowFunc("field2"))...
stream.keyBy("field3").window().aggregate(AggFunc, new MyWindowFunc("field3"))...
```